# Countdown resetes if I reload the page - need to set it till some date

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I have countdown script which is starting anew if I reload the page. I need to set it working till some date.

Here is link for countdown timer view and also you can download and use it or see codes: https://timer.craftovdvlp.club/

And here is script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#countdown2').ClassyCountdown({
    end: '1388468325',
    now: '1378441323',
    labels: true,
    style: {
      element: "",
      textResponsive: .5,
      days: {
        gauge: {
          thickness: .01,
          bgColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.05)",
          fgColor: "#1abc9c"
        },
        textCSS: 'font-family:\'Open Sans\'; font-size:25px; font-weight:300; color:#34495e;'
      },
      hours: {
        gauge: {
          thickness: .01,
          bgColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.05)",
          fgColor: "#2980b9"
        },
        textCSS: 'font-family:\'Open Sans\'; font-size:25px; font-weight:300; color:#34495e;'
      },
      minutes: {
        gauge: {
          thickness: .01,
          bgColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.05)",
          fgColor: "#8e44ad"
        },
        textCSS: 'font-family:\'Open Sans\'; font-size:25px; font-weight:300; color:#34495e;'
      },
      seconds: {
        gauge: {
          thickness: .01,
          bgColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.05)",
          fgColor: "#f39c12"
        },
        textCSS: 'font-family:\'Open Sans\'; font-size:25px; font-weight:300; color:#34495e;'
      }

    },
    onEndCallback: function() {
      console.log("Time out!");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="http://timer.craftovdvlp.club/css/jquery.classycountdown.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://timer.craftovdvlp.club/js/jquery.classycountdown.js"></script>

<script src="http://timer.craftovdvlp.club/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<script src="http://timer.craftovdvlp.club/js/jquery.throttle.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div id="countdown2" class="ClassyCountdownDemo"></div>

</div>
```

P.S. if anyone has or know link of beautiful line circular countdown timer, I will be very thankful for help)

Comment: What do you mean "Starting anew"? It seems like you've hard-coded the value for `now` - if you want the countdown to remain relative to your endpoint, shouldn't `now` be set to... well... *now*? Furthermore, you should host the `.js` file for this plugin and use the "Add External Library" tool in your snippet so that your issue is reproduceable.

Comment: Now I added all includes. Yes I have now in file **http://timer.craftovdvlp.club/js/jquery.classycountdown.js** , even if i add date and write format ON, still it does not see date and works same or chrashs

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you reload a page, the memory will reset. Try using something persistent like a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) which stores the timer end-date.

The `now` should also be created every time you reload the page, as stated in @Himanshu Upadhyay's answer and in @Santi's comment.

I.E.

```
var end = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)timerEnd\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
end = end || '' + Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000; // 15 minutes
document.cookie='timerEnd=' end;
$('#countdown2').ClassyCountdown({
    end: end,
    now: '' + Date.now(),
    // ...etc
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. timer is crashes if I change even NOW... same for END

Answer (score 0):

Get current time variable now like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var now = d.getTime();

    $('#countdown2').ClassyCountdown({
        end: '1388468325',
        now: now,
        ....
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Now should work now, but how do work END ? how to set end date from now?

Comment: generally end date would be fixed. Upto which count down will go.

Comment: `var dEnd = new Date('2017-07-04 12:00:00');  var timeEnd = dEnd.getTime();` - Replace the date/time with whatever you want and set `end: timeEnd`

Comment: @Santi it changed behavior, changed day time, i think now problem is in `now: Date.now(),`. I think it can not find now date ( takes it randomly ) and for each refresh page sets different minutes and seconds. I will changed code in link to show you. Link: http://timer.craftovdvlp.club/

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay now I think it s get date problem. I changed Santi`s code in my file and you can see behavior from link: timer.craftovdvlp.club.

Comment: You just keep end value as it is. But change now value as I shown in my answer. Then see the timer will not get reset after you reload. It's the solution to your question.
I can help you further with your queries. You're welcome.!

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Now and END I think is works, but my timer is got crazy :) I changed code in my page, you can see it from link: [link](http://timer.craftovdvlp.club/). now it changes hour every 10 seconds and see minuts as seconds))) There is chaos )

Comment: @Orik3ll0 I checked your link, the timer working perfectly. What's wrong in it? Can you clear your browser's cache and check the page again ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay It should write there 1 day, some hours and etc.  but it show 513 days 1 hours and etc. :) I wrote date 2017-07-04 12:00:00. What about you? How many days left it shows for you? Do not forget to refresh page

Comment: @Orik3ll0 I think you should write something like `var dEnd = new Date('2017-07-04 10:00:00');`

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay I did. I did changes which advise me Santi: `var dEnd = new Date('2017-07-04 12:00:00'); var timeEnd = dEnd.getTime();` Maybe there are some problem...

Comment: @Orik3ll0 you did not notice the time I wrote in my previous comment.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Why would a 2 hour difference in time make the page suddenly work?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay I noticed and changed as you wrote but paste here Santi date. Also, I played with date and time, still same. I think I have to find another countdown, this one is problem maybe.

Comment: Dear Santi and HimanshuUpadhyay I found one more countdown which has more simple JS and I made it work. [HERE IS LINK](http://timer2.craftovdvlp.club/) (If you want to download it, tell me i will send link).Now I have to find how to make it responsive... Thank you for your help, unfortunately there are something is missing from our eyes and that`s why it is working wrong.